# Check if prime number using recursive and no loop in turbo c

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, turbo-c

Good Day,

I'm trying to make a code that would determine the prime numbers between two numbers. This should be done recursively and without any loop. So far I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void prime(int x, int y){
    int waa;
    if(x <= y){
        waa = isPrime(x);
        if(waa==1 || waa == 0){
             printf("");
         }else{
             printf("%5d",waa);
         }
        prime(x+1,y);
    }
}

int isPrime(int n, int i){
    i = 2;
    if(i<n){
        if(n%i==0 && n!=2 && n!=i){
         return(0);
        }else{
            return(n);
        }
         i++;
         isPrime(n,i);      
    }
}

void main(){
    int num[2];
    clrscr();

    printf("Input 2 numbers: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &num[0], &num[1]);
    prime(num[0], num[1]);
    getch();
}
```

the output between 1 and 10 is: 2,2,3,5,7,9.
expected output: prime numbers 2,3,5,7

Would anyone be able to help me with this.

much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Your code does not compile, in part because of this line:  `waa = isPrime(x);`  *(wrong number of arguments)*.  Since you claim you already got output, **post code that works**.

Comment: @abelenky sorry to disappoint you but it does compile im using Turbo C++ IDE. i don't know whats wrong with your compiler but mine works, gives a warning though but it still compiles

Comment: First you cited Turbo C and tagged the question `[C]`.  Now you're referring to Turbo C++ (C and C++ are different).  Even if your code compiles, take a look at the line `isPrime(x)` and the defined function `isPrime(int n, int i)`.  Can you tell me how they're compatible?

Comment: Turbo C++ can compile either C or C++. you can google it if you want though.

Comment: @magicianiam that warning is there for a reason and if you bothered to (a) read it and (b) understand what is *actually* happening the bug would come obvious. I'd also suggest using a compiler that's not at least a decade old and full of bugs. Hint: snarky replies, like your comment to abelenky, make us much less inclined to bother answering your questions and much more inclined to leave you to your own devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be simpler if function isPrime just checks whether the given integer is prime or not and outputs a Boolean value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void prime(int x, int y){
    int waa;
    if ( x == 1 ) x++;
    if(x <= y){
        waa = isPrime(x,2); // second input parameter added
        if(waa != 0){
            printf("%5d",x);
         }
        prime(x+1,y);
    }
}

int isPrime(int n, int i){
    if(n%i==0 && n!=2 && n!=i){
      return(0);
    } else {
       if (i < sqrt(n)) {
            return( isPrime(n,i+1) );
        } else
         return 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    int num[2];

    printf("Input 2 numbers: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &num[0], &num[1]);
    prime(num[0], num[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1
10
```

Output:

```
2 3 5 7
```

http://ideone.com/gyW7ED

Comment: what should i include for bool?

Comment: i get undefined symbol for bool though

Comment: Sorry! C does not have any built in Boolean types. Change all bools to ints and then try. I have edited my answer.

Comment: got it, but the problem now is that i doesn't print anything after i input the 2 numbers, i'm guessing it goes to return(0) all the time

Comment: I have added the full code with tested input and output. If it still does not work, then you may have to change your compiler. Note: you will have to include math.h

Comment: Sorry about that, it was my fault forgot to add math.h, also thank you for the help. it is greatly appreciated. :) though would you mind explaining why is the sqrt part for and what was causing my code to print non prime numbers? thank you again

Comment: You need to check for factors only upto sqrt(n). That is because, if there is a factor greater than sqrt(n), it will have to be multiplied by a number less than sqrt(n) to get n. You would have already checked that smaller number and found out whether it is, or is not a factor of n.

Comment: C does have a built-in Boolean type as of C99 called `_Bool`, and the inclusion of `<stdbool.h>` allows you to use `true`, `false` and `bool` in place of `1`, `0` and `_Bool` respectively. However, Turbo C++ AFAIK won't have any of that because of how old it is.